# Apache2 doesn't start automatically in an OpenVZ container using Debian 6

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, openvz

I have a OpenVZ container running Debian 6 on my server. After every restart of the container I have to manually start the Apache2 web server using its init script. In the error log I can't find any useful information.

Every suggestion is appreciated :-).

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` after container restart

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Apache2 is not registered as a service in your container? 
If so you may run `insserv /etc/init.d/apache2` in the OpenVZ container to star apache at boot.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I executed the command you proposed, it executed without any feedback. Any other suggestions?

Comment: well the insserv command does not output anything, did you restart the container after running that command to see if apache is starting at boot? If it isn't can you check the apache error log to see if there are any errors there?